# PCB stub antenna impedance matching

Tags: rf, filter

I'm about to design a 433MHz transceiver and found a nice reference design using the TRC105 and the RF3608D SAW Filter.

Before designing the circuit I wanted to understand the impedance matching in the reference design, and figure that would be no problem on my smith chart... Now hours later I still don't get it.

In the datasheet for the RF3608D on page 2 is drawn a Application Circuit, which shows matching to a 50ohm antenna.

http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/347/rf3608d-33048.pdf

Looking at page 2 is shown an Application circuit.

I think the 220nH shunt inductor is to cancel the capacitive reactance, which I think is about -5.8ohm (read on page 7).

But I don't understand at all, what purpose is of the series LC circuit (5.6nH || 1.2pF)?

Comment: yeah, nice spelling by me... my brain was probably fried from trying to do the calculations.  ;-)

Comment: Brian's answer is fine. Why did you offer a bounty? If you don't understand his answer, just ask for explanation.

Comment: How do you know Brian's answer is fine? He is giving a very qualified guess, and might very well be correct, but I hoped someone knew for sure why the LC circuit was there...

Comment: Your question is what the purpose of the series LC circuit is, Brian answers that question. In general, I consider it to be a bit weird to offer a bounty on a question with upvoted answers while you didn't even try to ask for improvement of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a parallel L-C circuit, tuned to about 2GHz, in series with the input.

Exactly why it's there isn't clear, but the broadband response on page 3 shows fairly poor rejection around 2GHz, so additional attenuation there may be important in some applications.